# Inserting data into table with a large number of columns

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I have a table with about 200 or so columns. I want to know the best way to insert this data into MySQL using Jooq.

Right now, I am using POJOs across my program to handle/transform my data. My problem is that, as far as I understand it, if I want to create a POJO I have to call .set{column name}. There is no generic .set method I can call on my POJO such as: .set(column, value).

Before anyone says it, I would be happy doing it the long way for 200 columns but I have about ten more tables of similar size that I would also need to do this for so this would be difficult to maintain.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is my understanding of the POJO api correct? I have looked through the config and I couldn't see anything that might help me.
2. What is the easiest way to do this outside of POJOs? My best idea at the moment is using Records

   ```
   Record test = conn.newRecord(table);
   Field<Object> field1 = field(name(table,col));
   test.set(field1, 10);
   ```

But I don't know if this is the correct way to do it (and if this is going to cause me grief down the line).

Comment: JPA, for instance eclipseLink, offers creating POJOs and O/R mapping. Maybe you can combine it. Otherwise write your own code generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "POJO" you mean jOOQ's generated POJOs, then yes indeed, there is no `set(column, value)` method as that would not be something you'd expect from a classic POJO (or JavaBean). jOOQ's records (as you've noticed) however, do have these methods. Records also support setting many values at once, e.g. from a `Map`, or from an array. See the [`Record.from(Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from-java.lang.Object-) method for details.

In other words, your usage of records is idiomatic for jOOQ. I don't see how this will cause "grief down the line".